How to add fields to nested JSON input structure
How to add fields to this nested structure? Also How to use a condition for overwrite operation?
In the provided JSON add srcDo value as sos under postalAddress object in jolt
Input :
{
  "ewc":true,
  "PartyPostalAddress": {
    "item": [
      {
        "BlBdrCd": {
          "addrTyp": "N"
        },
        "LNCd": {
          "addrTyp": "N"
        },
        "PostalAddress": {
          "SrcAddrLn1": "1 KWN",
          "SrcAddrLn2": "Second Floor",
          "SrcAddrLn3": "1569 WQAS Blvd"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "SrcDo": "N"
}

Expected :
{
  "PartyPostalAddress": {
    "item": [
      {
        "LNCd": {
          "addrTyp": "N"
        },
        "PostalAddress": {
          "sos":"N"
          "SrcAddrLn1": "1 KWN",
          "SrcAddrLn2": "Second Floor",
          "SrcAddrLn3": "1569 WQAS Blvd"
          
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}


Does this answer your question? Adding elements to the array based on condition

Hi Barbaros, It was useful I have accepted your solution. Thanks.

You can add such an attribute through use of a modify spec in which a key-value pair such as
"sos": "=(@(<int>,SrcDo))"
would be needed, where <int> should be determined by counting the layers to traversed to reach from the new location of the attribute to its original location ( a : and four { should be traversed, hence the value of the <int> should be 5 )
Then remove the attributes those you don't need such as
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "PartyPostalAddress": {
        "item": {
          "*": { //represents to indexes of the "item" array 
                 //unlike to an object nesting case
            "PostalAddress": {
              "sos": "=(@(5,SrcDo))"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { //remove undesired elements
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "PartyPostalAddress": {
        "item": {
          "*": {
            "BlBdrCd": ""
          }
        }
      },
      "ewc|SrcDo": ""
    }
  }
]

Alternatively you can use a shift transformation spec such as
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "PartyPostalAddress": {
        "item": {
          "*": {
            "LNCd": "&3.&2[&1].&",
            "PostalAddress": {
              "@(4,SrcDo)": "&4.&3[&2].&1.sos",
              "*": "&4.&3[&2].&1.&" //all attributes within the "PostalAddress" object
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

